# Supporting a subset of ODF in a .net application

Tags: .net, odf, opendocument

I'm building a simple CMS for an ASP.net-based website and would like to store the site content in files that use a subset of the ODF file format. Ideally, the site should be able to save the content created in a format that any ODF-compliant editor can open and edit.

It should also be able to open any ODF compliant file and load it if all the file's elements are within the subset we're supporting. If it contains elements that are not supported by the CMS, the CMS should report what those unsupported elements are.

Is there a .net library for handling this sort of thing or do I need to build one? I'd hate to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Within the context of the question asked, there is a library called AODL that solves most of the problems raised. The project is only half done and hasn't seen any check-ins since 2008, but seems to cover all of the word processing functionality I need.